# Problemas com uso do return

Tags: python-3.x

Meu código:

```
def a():
       print(1 + 1)
       n = input()
       print(2)
```

Não sei como retornar apenas o "n" fora da função para usá-lo com um "if". Ex.:

```
if n in ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que você queira fazer isto:

```
def foobar():
    print(1 + 1)
    n = input()
    print(2)
    return n # retona aqui

bar = foobar() # Pega o valor de n e coloca na variável baz

print(baz) # exibe baz

if baz in ...: # Aqui iria a sua if
```

Em outro exemplo, conforme o seu comentário

> Adicionei 2 returns um para quando estiver tudo certo e o `s` for menor que 8 e um `return None` que é para acaso ocorra de retornar mais que 8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# tudo que estiver indentado esta dentro do escopo da "função"
def begin():
    s = []

    for c in range(0,4):
        s.append( int( input() ) )

    if sum(s) < 8:
        print('Error 01: Invalid Input. Type other 4 numbers.')
        return None # <--- Aqui tem um RETURN dentro da IF, retorna None em caso de erro

    return s # <--- Aqui tem um RETURN fora da IF, termina a "função" e retorna o valor para quem a chamou

# retornou um chamada e setou para foo
foo = begin()

# retornou um chamada e setou para bar
bar = begin()

print(foo) # exibe o valor da variável foo
print(bar) # exibe o valor da variável bar
```

Comment: Fiz mudanças no código, pode me explicar como eu faria para retornar o "s", só que de novo fora da função, nesse caso?                                                                                                        def  begin():
 s = []
 for c in range(0,4):
     s.append ( int(input()) )
 if sum(s) < 8:
     print('Error 01: Invalid Input. Type other 4 numbers.')
     begin()
begin()

Comment: E desculpe, mas não sei como colocar o código de forma correta nos comentários.

Comment: @LucasSouza editei a resposta, veja se é isto o que deseja

Comment: Está dando erro de identação na parte do "return s".

Comment: @LucasSouza editei novamente e revisei os espaços aproveitei e adicionei o utf8 por causa dos acentos, copia da forma que esta e cola em um novo documento sem nada e tenta executar.